# TailwindCSS 3 classes doesn't override previous classes

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am facing an issue which is mind-numbing in the world of CSS.
TailwindCSS 3 classes just doesn't override previous classes.

For example, there is this component, I created:

```
import * as React from "react";

const TextBox = ({ addClassName, children }) => {
  const className = `text-xl leading-7.5 font-lato font-normal ${addClassName}`;
  return <div className={className}>{children}</div>;
};

export default TextBox;
```

Then I go ahead and use this component above at another place, like this:

```
<TextBox addClassName="text-4xl">My New Text</TextBox>
```

Now when I inspect it in the browser, it shows both of the font-size:
[Screenshot from the browser inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpMZA.png)

```
class="text-xl leading-7.5 font-lato font-normal text-4xl"
```

As you can see both of the classes are there, both referring to font-size, and the larger one is **after** the smaller one.

And still **ONLY** the small ( the original ) font-size will be the dominant.

( as a side note, I did try to put the *addClassName* variable in the front as well, no help )

Why is this?

I appreciate any help getting with this.
Thank you

Comment: I cannot find an announcement for this to be supported in tailwind 3.
Link to docs?

Comment: Not sure I follow what you meant Felix

Comment: What I mean is that I don't think meaningful order of classes is supported by tailwind V3. Hence, I was wondering why you think it is supported and if you have a link to documentation about that feature.

Comment: According to basic CSS, the style coming after another one overwrites the previous.
I tested it several times, that the new way Tailwind 3 generates classes, is that once you are using a certain class, it will be added to the commons.css file, then if you are using another one, it will be added after(!), and because of this order, the later one never(!) can overwrite the previous one. 
Example:
".text-4xl {
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
}
.text-sm {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.25rem;
}"

Comment: So in the example above, just because I used .text-4xl first and .text-sm later, the .text-4xl could never overwrite the .text-sm.

Comment: Anyone wrestling with this, keep in mind TW has a modifier for `!important` which allows class-to-override-class: e.g. `<MyComponent class="!font-bold">`. Whether this aligns with your design system, that is up to you. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#important-modifier

Answer (score 27):

I found the answer from [dev.to](https://dev.to/diogoko/overriding-tailwind-classes-in-react-4po3).
The reasons your code didn't work are:

> It turns out that the space-separated CSS class list that the class HTML attribute accepts is not treated as a list when calculating CSS rules precedence by the browser. The class attribute actually contains the set of classes the element has, so the order doesn't matter.

> As the order that the classes appear in the class attribute doesn't matter, the rule that comes later in the CSS stylesheets wins.

**Moreover, it wasn't warranted that the 'text-4xl' was defined after the 'text-xl' in the CSS stylesheet.**

So to solve this problem, I recommended using [tailwind-merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tailwind-merge) to override previous classes.

> Tailwind-merge is a utility function to efficiently merge Tailwind CSS classes in JS without style conflicts.

One of its features was: Last conflicting class wins

`twMerge('p-5 p-2 p-4') // → 'p-4'`

Answer (score 15):

I may be late for this but we can use `!` to mark a class as important. For example `!text-4xl`.

Comment: Easy, Simple and effective.

Comment: this is the simplest solution so far

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. `dark:text-white dark:!text-blue-500` https://play.tailwindcss.com/pKkz5ywPpo

Comment: Yes this. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

In essence, the order of classes in the class attribute does not matter; the class which has its CSS rule defined later takes precedence. See the [Multiple Same CSS Classes issue](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/1452) on the Tailwind CSS Github repository for more information on this phenomenon.

[Arbitrary variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-variants) can be used to increase the specificity of the generated selector to allow later classes to always be applied.

For instance, with `class="text-xl [&&]:text-4xl"` ([Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/yXJuLYr5an)), `text-4xl` will be applied over `text-xl` (the opposite of the behavior with regular `text-xl text-4xl` <sup>[Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/2gfY5tX545)</sup>).

To overwrite this again, just add more ampersands (`&`), e.g. `class="text-xl [&&]:text-4xl [&&&]:text-3xl"` ([Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/cUmmsX93Yk)) enables the final text size to be set the same as `text-3xl`. And so on.

Finally, in special cases, the [`!important` modifier](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#important-modifier) can be applied to override nearly anything else. This can be done by adding `!` in front of the class name, e.g. `class="text-xl !text-4xl"`. **Use this sparingly**, as it can make styles difficult to maintain and modify later on.

---

Another approach is to make all the classes in the component have lower specificity, rather than making the styles passed into the component have higher specificity.

This can be done by replacing all the class names inside the component that might be overriden with `[:where(&)]:className`. For example, `class="[:where(&)]:text-xl text-4xl"` will result in the `text-4xl` class being applied.

Comment: This is by far, the simpler solution. Would be nice there is a way to declare less precedence as well, that way consumers of components won't have to add [&&]. But by far this is the best solution so far

Comment: @royriojas You can do that in the component by setting classes with `[:where(&)]:className`. I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Increasing the ampersands worked for me, but I don't understand why that worked. What is the increasing of ampersands doing? I didn't find this custom variant in the Tailwind documentation.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, and didn't want to add yet another dependency and increase my app's bundle size just to solve something that doesn't have to be this hard. So I looked into the [tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#adding-component-classes) and found this:

> Use the components layer for any more complicated classes you want to
> add to your project that you’d still like to be able to override with
> utility classes.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .card {
    background-color: theme('colors.white');
    border-radius: theme('borderRadius.lg');
    padding: theme('spacing.6');
    box-shadow: theme('boxShadow.xl');
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

> By defining component classes in the components layer, you can still
> use utility classes to override them when necessary:

```
<!-- Will look like a card, but with square corners -->
<div class="card rounded-none">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Though this means you will have to write a component class every time you want to override an element with predefined classes.

**UPDATE:**

There is now a simpler way, using [tailwind-merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tailwind-merge) you can now achieve this without the need to create a component every time you want to override a default set of classes.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [redit](https://www.reddit.com/r/tailwindcss/comments/mnblk3/why_wont_the_latest_class_override_the_first_class/)

> In CSS if you have two selectors with equal specificity the one that comes last in the CSS structure takes precedence. The order in the class attribute has no effect.

Suggested solution would be to write your own class after tailwindcss import statement, or edit it using inline style.

My personal tip: **Don't use two classes that target the same css property**, `text-lg` and `text-4xg` both target `font-size`, you need a way (suggest clsx lib) to put only one class name and not the other

```
import clsx from 'clsx';


let condition = false;

function Component(){


  return (
    <div>
     <p className={clsx({
       "text-lg": condition,
       "text-4xl": !condition,
     })}>
     ...
     </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Really want to underline that last sentence. Don't target the same css property twice. In that case the rule wins, which is declare later - and you have no control over that in tailwind. 
You can use clsx to conditionally add tailwind classes. However in clsx you always have to state the entire logic for every classname-collection (e.G. "text-lg text-red" : !a && b) which can get messy, which is why I have started to put the logic to discern which className gets added to the css inside functions and call them inside clsx.

That tailwind-merge koi ngyuen mentioned might also be a goto option

Comment: I use the `classnames` library but this is exactly the approach I take

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to install any packages, you can add a custom **screen size** in your `talwind.config.js` that starts at 0px.

```
    ...
    theme: {
        extend: {
            screens: {
                priority: '0px' 
            }
        }
    }
    ...
```

So when you want to overwrite previous classes you just add `priority:` before the class like `priority:text-4xl`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to implement your own class overriding system, then you might be interested in using arbitrary values. I have noticed that arbitrary value classes have a higher precedence than default class names in Tailwind.
For example:
className="text-xl text-[36px]",
Tailwind will use the latter CSS rule. This is not a scalable solution. But, in rare cases, it can be used a simple and fast solution.

Comment: 100% right! I got to the same conclusion as of lately. Of course this is only usable in Tailwind v3.0!

Answer (score 0):

The [tailwind-unimportant](https://github.com/mwnciau/tailwindcss-unimportant) plugin for Tailwind solves this problem if you don't want to use `tw-merge` or aren't using JavaScript. It adds a variant that allows the component classes to be overridden.

Your example would become:

```js
const TextBox = ({ addClassName, children }) => {
  const className = `-:text-xl -:leading-7.5 -:font-lato -:font-normal ${addClassName}`;
  return <div className={className}>{children}</div>;
};
```

```js
<TextBox addClassName="text-4xl">My New Text</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
dark:*:text-black
```

> 

I am using "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1"

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to try [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx) or [clsssnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) for better usage with tailwind classes instead of string interpolation

Comment: I just tried it both, doesn't make a difference.
Looks like the problem is, how the TailwindCSS generates its commons.css file, and position one class above the other. For example I noticed, that class: "text-4xl" is before the class: "text-xl" in the css file tailwind generates, and that is why it doesn't overrides. But it would work the other way around. Now I just have to find a way how to make Tailwind 3 to generate classes in the right order.

Comment: What I ended up having to do is checking the `addClassName` for the classes that I want to override and then provide a default.

Comment: clsx does not solve this problem. clsx will just combine several input types to a single class name string, but will not identify any conflicts between the class names applied

Answer (score -1):

I found a Solution guys.
Setup **props** with default CSS values at the original component, and then at the time of the usage of this aforementioned component, if we need different style, we just gave that in the **props**.

Comment: This means that you will have to re-write all the default class names to only override one. Or create X number of props mapping each class name